# Tailwind class conflicts when used in Markdown with vitepress

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite, vitepress

I'm using `vitepress` for documenting our app. It reads markdown and renders it in vue components. Unfortunately there seems to be a conflict with a tailwind `default` class (setting all borders to `0` on button components) and a `button` I am applying the class to. The class works fine with components in the `src` folder but not with vitepress.

I've set it up in a `docs` directory in root:

[image]

The component not displaying the `border` is `MyButton.md`:

````
# MyButton

## Props

| Prop name | Description | Type    | Values | Default |
| --------- | ----------- | ------- | ------ | ------- |
| blub      |             | string  | -      |         |
| check     |             | boolean | -      |         |

## Events

| Event name | Properties | Description |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----------- |
| toggle     |            |

## Slots

| Name    | Description | Bindings |
| ------- | ----------- | -------- |
| default |             |          |

---

<button class="bg-orange-300 text-black border border-black rounded px-3 py-1.5 hover:bg-orange-400 transition">
  click me
</button>

```vue live
<MyButton blub="5" />
```
````

Tailwind is correctly imported in `custom.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --vp-c-brand: #f44300;
  --vp-c-green-dark: #ff8c00;
}

.VPDocOutlineDropdown {
  display: none !important;
}
```

which then get's loaded into `index.js`:

```
import DefaultTheme from 'vitepress/theme'
import './custom.css'

export default DefaultTheme
```

and further used in an extended default theme.

The vitepress `config.ts` looks like this:

```
import { SiteConfig } from 'vitepress'
import { generateSidebarConfig } from "./generate-sidebar"

// https://vitepress.dev/reference/site-config
const config: SiteConfig = {
  title: "blub",
  themeConfig: {
    // https://vitepress.dev/reference/default-theme-config
    nav: [
      { text: 'Home', link: '/' },
      { text: 'Examples', link: '/markdown-examples' }
    ],
    sidebar: generateSidebarConfig()
  }
}

export default config
```

I've tried adding the vitepress folders to `tailwind.config` but it doesn't help:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/App.vue',
    './src/**/*.js',
    './src/**/*.vue',
    './docs/.vitepress/theme/*.vue',
    './docs/.vitepress/theme/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The button is displayed without border:

[image]

Dev tools show that the `border` class is correctly applied to the button but then conflicting with the `button` selector:[image]

When I change the `button` to a `div`, the border is applied correctly.

Anything I can do to make the border class work correctly on button elements?

Comment: Use a `prefix: "tw"` in `tailwind.config.js` and then prefix all the TailwindCSS classes with `tw-`

Answer (score 0):

If you want Tailwind classes to have more priority over the default classes in VitePress, consider adding the `important` option in the tailwind.config.js file:

```
module.exports = { important: true}
```

[See the tailwind docs for reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important).